# Constructor issue in for-loop

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class *A*. I want to create few objects of type *A* and push them into a vector. There are many ways to do so, in particular the two illustrated below.
The first uses a for-loop, the second does not.

Apparently they should be equivalent, however if I print *this* in the constructor of the new objects, those within the loop share the same address.
I expected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public:
        A();
        ~A();
};


A::A() {
    std::cout << "this = " << this << std::endl;
}

A::~A() {}

int main() {

    std::vector<A> v;

    // Way 1 (with for loop)
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        v.push_back(A());

    // WAY 2 (without for)
    v.push_back(A());
    v.push_back(A());

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
this = 0x7ffe8ac35ef9     <- these two are the same
this = 0x7ffe8ac35ef9     <- 
this = 0x7ffe8ac35efa
this = 0x7ffe8ac35efb
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Probably because the ctor youre seeing is for the object on the stack which is then copied into the vector, define the copy ctor and add a print in there too

Comment: Temporaries. They overlap.

Comment: Add an explicit `A(A const&);` copy constructor, and in the implementation output its address.

Comment: Actually I think the 2 outside of the loop should have the same address too. Why are they different?

Comment: @John Smith, It depends on compiler optimization. The compiler could expand the loop and then the addresses in the loop would be different

Comment: @DmytroDadyka But the temporary should be destroyed before the next statement. It's doesn't matter if it's in a loop or not.

Comment: @Eljay Or `A(A&&);`.  If a class has a move constructor, the `v.push_back(A());` will call it instead of the copy constructor.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I meant automatic vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, there is nothing that could alert you. Everything works as it should. In each iteration of the loop, you create a stack variable. Since all iterations of the loop are identical, the address of the local variables on the stack is identical. After creating a variable, you copy it into a vector and have two copies of the variable with different addresses - on the stack and on the heap (in the vector). After exiting the iteration, the local copy is destroyed, but another copy is saved in the vector. In the new iteration, an object will be created, obviously, at the same address as in the previous iteration.

Note that the stack usage depends on compiler optimization. For example for "Release" version you are likely to get an identical address in all four cases. On my compiler I got

```
this = 008FFA63
this = 008FFA63
this = 008FFA63
this = 008FFA63
```